# Let $G$ be a abelian group and $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup. Prove: There exists homomorphism $Q$ such that $\ker Q=H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

> Let $G$ be a abelian group and $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup. Prove: There exists homomorphism $Q$ such that $\ker Q = H$.

So far I've tried to define homomorphism $Q$ such that $\ker Q = H$ with no success. I'm not even sure how to use the fact that $G$ is abelian.

Any hints will be useful.

Comment: The answers below are sufficient for your question, but it is important to know that every normal subgroup in a group $G$ is a homomorphism kernel which is a more general case.

Comment: Just a remark, given that you already got some answers: in full generality, normal subgroups are *exactly* the subgroups which appear as the kernels of group homomorphism, and the fundamental theorem on homomorphism basically says that the image of such a homomorphism is fully determined (up to natural isomorphism) by the kernel. So in a sense, the homomorphisms given in the answers are the only ones possible, up to relatively minor differences.

Comment: The kernel of a homomorphism is always a subgroup. But if $G=\Bbb Z_p$ and $H=\{ [2]_p, \dots,  [p-1]_p\}\subset G$, then $H\not\le G$, so it cannot by a kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : $Q :  G \to G/H  $

by $Q(g) =g+H$

Comment: How did you come up with this solution?

Comment: @aaabbb It's the well known (and extremely useful) [canonical homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_map)

Answer (score 2):

Since $G$ is abelian, every subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$ (you can prove this straightly from the definition of normal subgroup). In particular $H$ is normal in $G$, so the quotient $ G / H$ is a group itself. Then as it's also menioned above, define $Q$ in the following way
$$ \begin{cases} Q: &G \to G/H \\ &g \mapsto g \cdot H \end{cases} $$
Try to prove that this $Q$ between these two groups is actually a homomorphism between them; And then determine it's kernel.

---

**Edits** (See the discussion below with @Shaun)

Note that if $H$ is an arbitrary subset of $G$, there might not be any homomorphism $Q$ that $ \mathrm{ker} (Q) =H$; this is because every kernel of a homomorphism from $G$ to any other group, must be a subgroup of $G$ (you can also prove this directly). And so the statement of your question is flawed, and $H$ must have assumed to be (at least) a subgroup.

Comment: But $H$ is not necessarily a subgroup (unless the OP is mistaken).

Comment: @Shaun But how could $H$ not be a (normal) subgroup if it's a kernel of a homomorphism? That way the question is asking to prove something wrong.

Comment: We don't know that *a priori*. The question only assumes $H\subseteq G$.

Comment: @Shaun I think your point does not contribute to a flaw in the argument I made, but it does contribute to the problem in the question, so I edited this answer to reflect it.

Comment: That's much better. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaun thank you for pointing out.

Comment: $H$ Is a subgroup, Sorry for the confusion :)